# Angular Router ActivatedRoute

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I want to check the address bar if it contains "admin" or not

Address: http://localhost:4200/admin

```
constructor(
private route: ActivatedRoute
 ){
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap: ParamMap) =>{
  console.log(paramMap.has('/admin'));
  }
)
```

but it gives me false.
I expected true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this in constructor, use `Location` service instead of router:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private location: Location){
  if (this.location.path().startsWith('/admin')) {
    console.log('true');
  }
}
```

`Router.url` is initialised with `/` (and populated with real url later), while `Location.path()` will return the real url right away.

Comment: You're welcome! Could you please accept this answer if it solves your problem? Otherwise it will get more attention while it is already answered.